# First time AJAX, examples not working for me

Tags: c#, jquery, html, ajax

I was trying to call a c# class method, using a HTML button.
In another topic people advised me to use AJAX. I've looked at different tutorials and tried implementing it but sofar its just not working for me.

For now i just want the button to give me a pop-up (just so I know the method is being called) the method i want to call is setLang(string lang) from the class HomeController

this is how i have my onclick event

```
<input type="submit" onclick="setLanguage();" value="submit">
```

and this is the script part, i have this in same page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setLanguage() {
var lang = "en";
$.post('@Url.Action("setLang","HomeController")/' + lang,function(){
//i'm not expecting a result to process
});
}
</script>
```

but nothing happens when i click my button.

am i missing something here?

edit: the function is getting called, but the callback isnt

UPDATE: still not working, this is my current code (by request)

button (index.aspx)

```
<input type="button" onclick="setLanguage();" value="submit">
```

function (index.aspx)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setLanguage() { 
alert("this message shows");       
    $.post('Url.Action("setLang","Home")/?lang=' + lang,
        function (data) {
            alert("this message does not");
        });
 }
</script>
```

in HomeController.cs

```
   public JsonResult setLang(string lang)
    {       
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(lang);
        .....//a lot more code, until it reaches
        return Json("Language: " + lang);
    }
```

Comment: what is lang in this context?  You should do var lang = "en";

Comment: its a string containing the language , i actually want it as parameter, but i figured i 'd try it like this first, i edited my post, added the 'var' part

Comment: What are you expecting the `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show` to do within an asp.net MVC application?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console. I think you've included JQuery? And... what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: DeadManWalking MessageBox in client or in server?

Comment: if you want to have an popup message use JavaScript instead. `alert('test')` in the callbackfunction

Comment: @DeadManWalking `System.Windows.Forms` is for Windows Forms and not an asp.net application. From your Controller Action, you would want to return some value to the AJAX call.

Comment: well to make a long story short: i want to call a C# method, in my HTML.
i have no console errors

Comment: @Tim B James sorry if this is a stupid question, but why would i want to return a value ? im calling a 'void' method

Comment: @DeadManWalking when calling a method via AJAX, it would be best to return something to it. Otherwise how will you know that it has worked?

Comment: with AJAX you can't explicit one method. the only thing you can do is to give your application parameters. With control structures inside yout application you could call the method you want to use.

Comment: @kuh-chan alert('test') in the callback does nothing. but when i put it in the first function(dont know what that is called) then i do get the message
maybe this is why Tim B James wants me to return something? :P ill giv it a try

Comment: ouch, @kuh-chan, you totally confused me now lol it is not possible to call a method from my c# class? that is kinda the whole point im using ajax

Comment: No. AJAX doesn't do anything else than a HTTP-request and returning the output the called file gave. So... you need a logic in your application that calls the method

Comment: Have you added `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]` above your class definition, to enable Ajax calls?

Comment: let me refrase my last comment, how can it even return a value if it cant run my method?

Comment: @DeadManWalking its difficult to follow if you keep changing your example code. Its easier if you add an update with your changed code instead of replacing it.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your Index view of the HomeController:

```
<input type="button" onclick="setLanguage();" value="submit">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function setLanguage() {
        var lang = "en";
        $.post('@Url.Action("setLang","Home")/?lang=' + lang,
            function (data) {
                alert(data);
        });
    }
</script>
```

I've changed a couple of things compared to your code:

- input type = button
- The controller name should be 'Home', not 'HomeController'. ASP.NET MVC adds the 'controller' part by default
- Your success functions takes a data parameter and executes a javascript alert on the client machine.
- Because you have no routes setup for this specific method, I've changed the lang parameter to be a part of your query string.

Then on the server add the following action method to your HomeController

```
public JsonResult setLang(string lang)
{
    return Json("Language: " + lang);
}
```

The function takes your lang parameter and then returns a JsonResult with only a simple string value. Json is the preferred way of sending data between a browser and the server.

You can expand this example and return more complex data to your browser.

Comment: thanks for your reaction, still no luck however :(
the callback function seems never to be executed

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console? You can use Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see which requests are send. This is a great tool for debugging web applications.

Comment: yeah i have fiddler, it throws an 500 error on http://localhost:57688/@Url.Action(%22setLang%22,%22Home%22)/?lang=en

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET WebForms or MVC? When using MVC, that url should be expanded to localhost:57688/home/setlang?lang=en

Comment: Fiddler shows you the URL containt 'Url.Action'. Normally, MVC should execute this code when rendering the page. What do you see in the source view of your page?

Comment: when i press the button, i just stay on the page i'm on, which is the behaviour i expect, but the callback isnt executed, i expect the callback to give me the alert(response), so the source vie just gives me the code of that page

Comment: Yes I understand. That's what we are trying to fix :) If a 500 error is returned, Fiddler should show you more information in the response. A 500 error means a server error so there should be some exception details. Can you show them?

Comment: oow, the error was a wrong parameter in my cookie creation somewhere else on my page , fixed it, and now nothing happens in fiddler when i press the button

Comment: Please update your question with your current code and status or start a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are calling the action method via **POST** Http type, Make sure that your Action method is also ready to respond HTTPPostType request. You may need to add the `HttpPost` annotation to your action method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult setLang(string id)
{
  return Content("MVC is awesome");
}
```

To handle a response from the action method, use the call back method with an argument. In the below example, you will get the response from the action method in the variable `data`.

```
<input type="submit" value="submit">
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){

   $("form").submit(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();  // preventing the default form submit behaviour
       var lang="en"
       $.post("@Url.Action("setLang","Home")/" + lang,function(data){
           alert(data);
       });

   });

 });
</script>
```

Comment: @jrummell: Oh Yea ! I missed that!. Thanks for pointing out. corrected now.